# Como agregar un nuevo elemento al Navigation Drawer y editarlo como xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy con un proyecto en Android Studio, he implementado el Navigation Drawer que te proporciona Android Studio y lo he modificado para añadir nuevos elementos en el. Dejo el codigo por aquí:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inicio"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_apps_24"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_archivos"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_folder_copy_24"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ayuda"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_question_mark_24"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ajustes"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_settings_24"
            android:title="@string/ajustes" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/baseline_person_off_24"
            android:title="@string/cerrar_sesion"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Ahora, despues de añadir estos nuevos items en el menu, quiero hacer que estos redirijan a un fragmeto .xml que pueda edtitar, he probado a añadir una nueva actividad desde el archivo mobile_navigation.xml pero cuando lo hago solo se me genera un archivo .java pero no un .xml para poder editar.

También he intentado copiar el codigo de los otros fragmentos e intentar modificarlo pero no he coseguido que funcione.

Comment: Hola. ¿Estás usando el [Componente de Navegación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started?hl=es-419)? Si es así, tienes que agregar en él un nuevo destino que apunte al nuevo item que has agregado a Navigation Drawer y listo, no tienes que hacer nada más.

Comment: Como lo estas tratando de realizar, agregalo por favor